# OdooV8 - Why does it take so long to create a record in 'res_partner' in my case

Tags: python, methods, odoo, odoo-8

I recently started to develop with odoo8 and I've met a problem.

My problem is that I have two classes : *'helpdesk'* and *'res_partner'* and I don't know why my code stuck for a long time when I create a new record in 'res_partner' but when I comment this block of codes (below) my code works great.

```
self.env['res.partner'].create({
    'name': nameFmt,
    'firstname': self.firstNameOfUser.strip().lower().title(),
    'lastname': self.lastNameOfUser.strip().upper(),
    'birthdate': newDateFmt,
    'birth_place': self.pBirthOfUser,
    'is_company': False
})
```

*'helpdesk'* class has several fields and methods to get information, and computes them from the user inputs. Once the information computed, I create my record which is a new partner.

How I tried to solve my problem, I :

- Launched odoo in shell mode with '--debug' option and a pdb where the code is stuck (it's stuck at the *'create'* method as I said)
- Read some threads and documentations about my problem, but most are in v7 for the *create* method and anybody has been stuck like this for the creation of a record
- Checked each value that I sent to create my new record
- Saw the behavior of records and how they are stored with phpPgAdmin

For more information, this is my entire method definition :

```
@api.one
def addPartnerInDB(self):
    if (not self.firstNameOfUser or
        not self.lastNameOfUser or
        not self.dobOfUser or
        not self.pBirthOfUser):
        raise ValidationError(u"Tous les champs sp\u00E9cifi\u00E9s pour "
                              u"cette demande doivent \u00EAtre remplis !")
    # Avoid concurrent drop-down
    self.dropDownList1 = False
    self.dropDownList3 = False
    # Get every partners
    listOfPartners = self.env['res.partner'].search(
        [
            ('is_company', '=', False)
        ]
    )
    # Avoid useless compute for each iteration
    newDateFmt = u"".join(datetime.datetime\
                          .strptime(str(self.dobOfUser), "%Y-%m-%d")\
                          .strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    newFNameFmt = self.firstNameOfUser.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower()
    newLNameFmt = self.lastNameOfUser.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower()
    newBPFmt = self.pBirthOfUser.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower()
    matchedPartners = []
    # Fetch partner specified by the user
    for p in listOfPartners:
        if (newFNameFmt == p.firstname.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower() and
            newLNameFmt == p.lastname.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower()):
            matchedPartners.append(p)
    partnerAlreadyExist = False
    # If the list is not empty, then the fetch is enhance
    if (matchedPartners):
        for m in matchedPartners:
            partnerDOB = False
            partnerBP = False
            if (not isinstance(m.birthdate, bool)):
                if (newDateFmt == m.birthdate):
                    partnerDOB = True
            if (not isinstance(m.birth_place, bool)):
                if ((newBPFmt
                     == m.birth_place.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower())):
                    partnerBP = True
            # If one of them it's true, the user already exist
            if (partnerDOB or partnerBP):
                partnerAlreadyExist = True
                # Avoid useless iteration
                break
    # If the user specified doesn't exist he's created
    if (not partnerAlreadyExist):
        # Encode the string to avoid UnicodeError and further string errors
        nameFmt = (self.lastNameOfUser.strip().upper(),
                   + u" "
                   + self.firstNameOfUser.strip().lower().title())
        self.env['res.partner'].create(
            {
                'name': nameFmt,
                'firstname': self.firstNameOfUser.strip().lower().title(),
                'lastname': self.lastNameOfUser.strip().upper(),
                'birthdate': newDateFmt,
                'birth_place': self.pBirthOfUser,
                'is_company': False
            }
        )
    else:
        raise ValidationError(u"L'utilisateur renseign\u00E9 "
                              u"existe d\u00E9j\u00E0 !")
```

**EDIT**

After several attempts to debug my code with pdb, I noticed that something went wrong in the *for* statement when I compare firstnames and lastnames :

```
for p in listOfPartners:
    if (newFNameFmt == p.firstname.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower()
            and newLNameFmt == p.lastname.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower()):
       # Append element
```

Indeed, pdb blocks (2/3 sec) for each start of *for* statement before it gives me the hand back.

**For example :**

`(pdb) ->if (newFNameFmt == p.firstname.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower() and 
          # stuck 2-3 seconds
 (pdb) -> newLNameFmt == p.lastname.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower()):`

This behavior continues for about the first iterations of the *for* statement, after this amount of iterations, this behavior is no longer adopted for the rest of the iterations. Once I arrived at the *create* statement (with pdb), the creation record is miraculously unlocked and the code works.

I still don't know why this problem occurs and I still don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer for my question, and I think to know where the problem came from.

> **Where was my problem**

So the problem came from my first `for` statement which is :

```
   listOfPartners = self.env['res.partner'].search(
        [
            ('is_company', '=', False)
        ]
    )

    for p in listOfPartners:
        if (newFNameFmt == p.firstname.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower()
             and newLNameFmt == p.lastname.strip().replace(" ", "-").lower()):
            matchedPartners.append(p)
```

Theoretically nothing could be wrong with the `for` and `search` statements since they do what I want to do. But the problem is that each iteration that the program did in this `for` was 'n' queries sent to the PostgresSQL server (where `n` corresponds to the number of time that `p` is used in each iteration. In my case `n` = 2). This issue escalated quickly since `search` returned me about a thousand of partners (which are represented by `id` of each record saved in `res.partner` that matched the `search` query). So in the `for` this corresponds to thousands of queries that I sent in a very short time to the PostgreSQL server, and it seems that this server couldn't handle this amount of requests in a very short time.

So the problem was not the code in himself, but the behavior that I gave to him. The result of that behavior gave another behavior to the PostgreSQL for the further queries that I will give via Odoo, like `create`.

> **How I solved it**

The solution for me was to use the [psycopg2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2/) module. This module allowing communication with the postgreSQL server. The main difference between both in my case was that Odoo stayed in communication with the PostgreSQL server even if I used `search` to get only values that I wanted. While `psycopg2` gived me a `list` (of `tuples`) that only contains "real" values and not an `id` like Odoo gave me with `search`.

Once again, I don't know if the solution that I choosed was the best or if the issue came from there like I said above but this solution works well for me and I hope it will help others users stuck in a problem  with the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

you got that issue because maybe you have compare 2 different type! In your case, you maybe try to compare between res_partner object and string type or another! That should be res.partner(2973,).id or res.partner(2973,).name ....

Comment: I understand what you mean but how can I correctly create my partner if I don't know in advance his new **id** ? Do I need to call another method to get this **id** before call **create** method ? Or something else ?

Comment: you can do this way: 
new_partner = self.env['res.partner'].create(
                {
                   .....
                }
            ) 
new_partner will be the partner you have created

Comment: I did what you say but I still get the warning issue and my **create** still stuck.